# No Incoming Peer Connection for Bittorrent Cient

Tags: python, twisted, bittorrent

I am creating a Bittorrent client using python and twisted for streaming media files and am successfully able to do so.

I am using the Twisted Framework for connecting to Trackers and Peers. I can retrieve the peer list from a tracker and connect to them by executing the `reactor.connectTCP()` function for each peer.

But my client is unable to listen for TCP connections. Meaning there is no incoming connections from the peer side. I am using `reactor.listenTCP()` at a given port for this. The same port that I use in the request packet I am sending for the announce request to the tracker.
The request packet I am sending to the tracker is generated as follows :

```
def udp_create_announce_request(connection_id, payload, s_port):
    action = 0x1 #action (1 = announce)
    transaction_id = udp_get_transaction_id()
    buf = struct.pack("!q", connection_id)                                  #first 8 bytes is connection id
    buf += struct.pack("!i", action)                                        #next 4 bytes is action 
    buf += struct.pack("!i", transaction_id)                                #followed by 4 byte transaction id
    buf += struct.pack("!20s", urllib.unquote(payload['info_hash']))        #the info hash of the torrent we announce ourselves in
    buf += struct.pack("!20s", urllib.unquote(payload['peer_id']))          #the peer_id we announce
    buf += struct.pack("!q", int(urllib.unquote(payload['downloaded'])))    #number of bytes downloaded
    buf += struct.pack("!q", int(urllib.unquote(payload['left'])))          #number of bytes left
    buf += struct.pack("!q", int(urllib.unquote(payload['uploaded'])))      #number of bytes uploaded
    buf += struct.pack("!i", 0x2)                                           #event 2 denotes start of downloading
    buf += struct.pack("!i", 0x0)                                           #IP address set to 0. Response received to the sender of this packet. IP decided by tracker. 
    key = udp_get_transaction_id()                                          #Unique key randomized by client
    buf += struct.pack("!i", key)
    buf += struct.pack("!i", -1)                                            #Number of peers required. Set to -1 for default
    buf += struct.pack("!i", int(urllib.unquote(payload['port'])))          #port on which response will be sent
return (buf, transaction_id)
```

Is there any error in creating the packets ? Or is there a different reason for no peers trying to connect to my cliet's port ? Could there be a problem in the Factory and Protocol implementation in Twisted ?

### EDIT

The order of reactor calls are as follows :

```
factory = protocol.ServerFactory()
factory.protocol = Echo
self.reactor.listenTCP(self.port, factory)    
for peer in peers:
    self.reactor.connectTCP(peer.ip, peer.port, peerProtocol, timeout=10) # Working Properly
reactor.run()
```

The Echo Protocol is Defined as:

```
class Echo(protocol.Protocol):
    """This is just about the simplest possible protocol""" 
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        "As soon as any data is received, write it back."
        print "Hello", data 
        # Never Printed
```

Also `$ netstat -na | grep '{PORT}'` where PORT is the listening Port, displays the correct Port set to listen

Comment: If know the ports that your doing a `reactor.listenTCP` on, you could try `telnet`ing or `netcat`ing into the ports while your script is running to see if your listen logic is live.  You would need to provide testing examples and code if you want any meaningful feedback on your factory and protocol definitions, they are extremely broad and malleable concepts (event within the confines of Twisted) and can go right or wrong in any number of ways.

Comment: I tried `netstat -na | grep '{PORT}'` and it shows the correct port as LISTEN. Also the Factory and Protocol I am using for testing is the basic Server Factory and Protocol copy pasted from the Twisted Examples.

Comment: Your edits help, could you also try `telnet`ing or `netcat`ing to prove that "Hello" does get printed. Given your `netstat` if you can fire off the Hello you'll have good proof that you have valid and working listening code.

Comment: @MikeLutz : Tried it with netcat 127.0.0.1, and it worked. Had to set up the port forwarding on my router for making it work on the WWW IP address. Thank You for all the feedbacks :)